# Send Raw Transaction Ethereum infura nodejs npm

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I'm currently trying to implement an ethereum Node Connection to my Typescript/ Node Project.

I'm connection to the "Infura" node server where i need to sign my transaction locally.
Well, anyway. I'm signing my transaction using the npm package "ethereumjs-tx" and everything looks great.
When i'm using "sendRawTransaction" from web3 my response is an tx-id which means my transaction should be allready in the Blockchain. Well... it isn't

My sign Transaction Function is below.

```js
private signTransactionLocally(amountInWei: number, to: string, privateKey: string = <PRIVATE_KEY>, wallet: string = <MY_WALLET>) {
        const pKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(privateKey, "hex");

        const txParams = {
            nonce: this.getNonce(true,wallet),
            //gas: this.getGasPrice(true),
            gasLimit: this.getGasLimit2(true),
            to: to,
            value: amountInWei,
            data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            chainId: "0x1"
        };

        // console.log(JSON.stringify(txParams));
        const tx = new this.ethereumTx(txParams);
        tx.sign(pKeyBuffer);
        return tx.serialize().toString("hex");

    }
```

Used Functions in "signTransactionLocally" :

```js
    private getGasLimit2(hex: boolean = false) {
        const latestGasLimit = this.web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit;
        return hex ? this.toHex(latestGasLimit) : latestGasLimit;
    }
    
        private getNonce(hex:boolean = false, wallet: string = "0x60a22659E0939a061a7C9288265357f5d26Cf98a") {
        return hex ? this.toHex(this.eth().getTransactionCount(wallet)) : this.eth().getTransactionCount(wallet);
    }
```

Running my code looks like following:

```js
this.dumpInformations();
const signedTransaction = this.signTransactionLocally(this.toHex((this.getMaxAmountToSend(false, "0x60a22659E0939a061a7C9288265357f5d26Cf98a") / 3 )), "0x38bc48f1d19fdf7c8094a4e40334250ce1c1dc66" );
        console.log(signedTransaction);
        
this.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction("0x" + signedTransaction, function(err: any, res: any) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log("transaction Done=>" + res);
        });
```

since sendRawTransaction results in console log:
[Node] transaction Done=>0xc1520ebfe0a225e6971e81953221c60ac1bfcd528e2cc17080b3f9b357003e34

everything should be allright.

Has anybody had the same problem? 
i Hope that someone could help me. Have a nice day!

Comment: I had similar issues, but in my case, i've learned that it can still generate a Tx id, but it won't actually process if the nonce is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

After dealing with these issues countless times; i'm pretty sure you are sending a **nonce** too high.

In these cases, the node will still return you a transaction hash, but your transaction will remain in the nodes **queue** and not enter the memory pool or be propagated to other nodes, **UNTIL**, you fill in the nonce gaps.

You could try the following :

- Use getTransactionCount(address, 'pending') - to include the txs that are int nodes queue & memory pool . But this method unreliable and won't deal with concurrent requests as the node needs time to assess the correct amount at any given time.
- Keep your own counter, without relying on the node (unless you detect some serious errors).
- For more serious projects, persist your counter / per address at the level of the database with locks to handle concurrency, making sure you give out correct nonces to each request.

Cheers